# Image Map in Wordpress (self-hosted) Blog Post

Tags: html, wordpress, image, dictionary

I can't seem to get any image maps to work on my wordpress site. I have tried inserting an image map via the HTML code that image-maps.com provides (pasted directly into the Wordpress post HTML editor), and all I get is the image (no clickable areas)...even though the HTML output result on image-maps gives me a working image map.

I have also downloaded an image map plugin and inserted the map via shortcode, but again, all I get is the image, no clickable areas.

I tried switching themes, thinking it might be my particular theme, but I still have the problem.

Any ideas?

I know some people have said to make sure only 1 map tag is used (vs. individual map tags added for each area), which I have made sure is the case, but still, not working! :\

Comment: Can you share the URL, so we can take a look?  I've used image maps in WordPress without issue (via shortcodes, not inserted directly, but they worked)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and thought I would post the answer in case anyone else is/was having this problem.

The images, both inserted in the image-maps.com program and the plugin, were larger than my content area. Therefore, the image was automatically being resized to fit the area, thus rendering any coordinates that had been outlined useless. So, the easy fix was to just resize the image to the width of my content area before uploading and setting coordinates for it.